# Why is R not angry with my tibble: the tale of the dangling comma that could

Tags: r, tibble

R wants things to be just so. Commands must be exactly correct, and quite rightly so.

Thus, dangling commas are bad.

For example, on a vector:

```
> c(1,)
Error in c(1, ) : argument 2 is empty
```

Or a data frame:

```
> data.frame(a = 1,)
Error in data.frame(a = 1, ) : argument is missing, with no default.
```

But not on a tibble for some reason:

```
> tibble(a = 1,)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
      a
  <dbl>
1     1
```

Why is it so? What's gone ... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the code works because the arguments to `tibble()` are name-value pairs which are processed using `rlang::quos()`.

`quos()` has an argument `.ignore_empty = c("trailing", "none", "all")`.

So the default for `.ignore_empty` is "trailing" - *i.e.* the last argument to `tibble` is ignored if empty. If you change this, you'll see an error:

```
tibble(a = 1, .ignore_empty = "none",)
Error in eval_tidy(xs[[i]], unique_output) : object '' not found
```

See `?tibble` and `?quos` for the details.